# How do I disable the "Next" button of wxPython wizard page?

Tags: python, wxpython, wizard

I have a wizard created using PyWizardPage.  It starts with a main page, and then the user is brought through two more pages asking him for input information.  One one of these pages, I've created two Browse buttons which ask the user to select two files.  Now, on this page, I want the Next button to be disabled until the user selects the files.

I have scoured this site and Google for answers and have read things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420780/disable-the-next-button-until-condition-is-met-on-single-page-of-wx-wizardpage) and [this](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Disabling-the-Next-button-on-a-wizard-page-td2353127.html) but can't seem to get my setup to work.

How do I disable just one button *until* the two Browse buttons are filled in?

As for my setup, I have a WizardPage class that I call to create each page in my wizard.

**mywizard.py**

```
import wx
import wx.wizard

class WizardPage(wx.wizard.PyWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.wizard.PyWizardPage.__init__(self, parent)
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None
        self.initializeUI(title)

    def initializeUI(self, title):      
        # create grid layout manager    
        self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)

    def addWidget(self, widget, pos, span): 
        self.sizer.Add(widget, pos, span, wx.EXPAND)

    # getters and setters 
    def SetPrev(self, prev):
        self.prev = prev

    def SetNext(self, next):
        self.next = next

    def GetPrev(self):
        return self.prev

    def GetNext(self):
        return self.next
```

Then, in a separate file, I have a function to create each page.  The function for the first page calls the functions to create the other pages.  I also use helper functions called "browse1" and "browse2" to open a `wx.FileDialog` and such.

**pages.py**

```
import wx
from mywizard import * 

def create_page1(wizard):
    page1 = WizardPage(wizard, "Page 1")
    d = wx.StaticText(...)
    page1.addWidget(d, (2, 1), (1,5))

    page2 = create_update_certs_page2(wizard)
    page3 = create_update_certs_page3(wizard)

    # Set links
    page2.SetPrev(page1)
    page1.SetNext(page2)
    page3.SetPrev(page2)
    page2.SetNext(page3)

    return page1

def create_page2(wizard):
    page2 = WizardPage(wizard, "Page 2")

    b1 = wx.Button(page2, -1, "Browse...", wx.DefaultPosition, (85, 23))
    b1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt: browse1(evt, page2)) 
    x1 = wx.TextCtrl(...) # the text area where the Browse path is populated

    b2 = wx.Button(page2, -1, "Browse...", wx.DefaultPosition, (85, 23))
    b2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt: browse2(evt, page2)) 
    x2 = wx.TextCtrl(...) # the text area where the Browse path is populated


    page2.addWidget(b1, ..., ...)
    page2.addWidget(b2, ..., ...)

    return page2
```

And the main code in **pages.py** is:

```
app = wx.App(redirect = False)
wizard = wx.wizard.Wizard(None, -1, "Some Title")
wizard.SetPageSize((500, 350))

mypage1 = create_page1(wizard)

# Let's go!
wizard.RunWizard(mypage1)
```

Now, it is under the `create_page2` function of `pages.py` that I want to put the code to disable the Next button *until* the two Browse buttons are filled in.

Doing this disables all Next buttons in the wizard:

```
wizard.FindWizardById(wx.ID_FORWARD).Disable()
```

Doing this also disables all Next buttons in the wizard:

```
for o in wizard.GetChildren():
    if 'Button' in str(type(o)) and o.GetLabel() == "&Next >" and x1.GetValue() == "" and x2.GetValue() == "":
    o.Disable()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Okay, so I tinkered with this a bit more and my code looks similar to Mike Driscoll's answer below.  Here is my setup.  I have three classes: `WizardPage` which creates a regular page, `MyWizard` which creates the first page and calls helper functions to create and link all the subsequent pages, and `WizardPageDisabled` which is the same as `WizardPage` but has the timer that you introduced with the ability to disable the Next button.  I added this last class because this functionality may be needed for pages that's not just the first page of the wizard.

Now, I've come to a part when I see a problem.  `WizardPage` uses the `PyWizardPage` constructor and `MyWizard` uses the `wx.Wizard` constructor.  If I create `WizardPageDisabled` using the `PyWizardPage` constructor, the line `forwardBtn.Disable()` returns the `NoneType has no attribute Disable` error.  If I use the `wx.Wizard` constructor, the page doesn't show up at all.

So in addition to my issue above, I guess another clarification question is: what is the difference between `PyWizardPage` and `wx.Wizard`?

Comment: have you tried `page1.GetNext().Disable()` ?

Comment: @Joran Beasley: no, I haven't.  Just tried it and it disables the whole page instead of just the Next button.  I then tried `page1.GetNext().FindWindowById(wx.ID_FORWARD).Disable()` and was told that `NoneType object has no attribute Disable`

Comment: :/ sorry I dont use a wx version that has that module ...

Comment: I believe wx.Wizard is the wizard class itself whereas PyWizardPage is basically a panel with some added wizardry added to make it work in a special manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sneaky one. I'm sure there's more than one way to do this, but the way I came up with uses a wx.Timer to check and see if the text controls have values. If they do, then then re-enable the button. By the way, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420780/disable-the-next-button-until-condition-is-met-on-single-page-of-wx-wizardpage) I gave (which you linked) for disabling the button some time ago does work. Joran was correct...

Anyway, here is my implementation:

```
import wx
import wx.wizard

class WizardPage(wx.wizard.PyWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.wizard.PyWizardPage.__init__(self, parent)
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None
        self.initializeUI(title)

    def initializeUI(self, title):      
        # create grid layout manager    
        self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)

    def addWidget(self, widget, pos, span): 
        self.sizer.Add(widget, pos, span, wx.EXPAND)

    # getters and setters 
    def SetPrev(self, prev):
        self.prev = prev

    def SetNext(self, next):
        self.next = next

    def GetPrev(self):
        return self.prev

    def GetNext(self):
        return self.next

########################################################################
class MyWizard(wx.wizard.Wizard):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.wizard.Wizard.__init__(self, None, -1, "Some Title")
        self.SetPageSize((500, 350))

        mypage1 = self.create_page1()

        forward_btn = self.FindWindowById(wx.ID_FORWARD) 
        forward_btn.Disable()

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.onUpdate, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(1)

        self.RunWizard(mypage1)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def create_page1(self):
        page1 = WizardPage(self, "Page 1")
        d = wx.StaticText(page1, label="test")
        page1.addWidget(d, (2, 1), (1,5))

        self.text1 = wx.TextCtrl(page1)
        page1.addWidget(self.text1, (3,1), (1,5))

        self.text2 = wx.TextCtrl(page1)
        page1.addWidget(self.text2, (4,1), (1,5))

        page2 = WizardPage(self, "Page 2")
        page3 = WizardPage(self, "Page 3")

        # Set links
        page2.SetPrev(page1)
        page1.SetNext(page2)
        page3.SetPrev(page2)
        page2.SetNext(page3)

        return page1

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onUpdate(self, event):
        """
        Enables the Next button if both text controls have values
        """
        value_one = self.text1.GetValue()
        value_two = self.text2.GetValue()
        if value_one and value_two:
            forward_btn = self.FindWindowById(wx.ID_FORWARD) 
            forward_btn.Enable()
            self.timer.Stop()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def main():
    """"""
    wizard = MyWizard()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    main()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I understand your concept and I ran your code which worked but I can't seem to make it work for my case.  In my case, the page in question happens to be the third page that I want the Next button to be disabled.  Also, the two lines related to `FindWindowById` seem to work for your code but when I add those lines in the `init` function of my classes, I always error on `NoneType has no attribute Disable` which is very frustrating.

Comment: Make sure you are calling FindWindowById using an instance of the Wizard class. Also for the third page, I suspect you'll want to only run that call when the third page is reached. Thus bind to the changing page event and check what page your on before you run it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I tinkered around with my code a bit more, made it look like your structure and then seemed to run into what I believe may be the crux of my issue so I wrote it as an edit at the bottom of my question.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Okay so after much headbanging and finnagling with my code, I finally managed to get it to work.  Thank you for providing me the model of what it should look like.

Comment: No problem. Glad you figured it out