# How do I pass information between pages of a wxPython PyWizardPage wizard?

Tags: python, wxpython, wizard

I have a wizard created using PyWizardPage.  It starts with a main page, and then the user is brought through several more pages asking him for input information.  On one of these pages, I've created a Browse button which ask the user to select a file.  Then, on the next page, I have a "Verify Details" thing which displays a box containing all the inputs that the user selected through the Wizard and asks him to make sure that the information is correct before continuing.

My problem is, I can't get any of the user input on previous pages to be passed into my "Verify Details" page.

For my setup, I have a WizardPage class that I call to create each page in my wizard.

**mywizard.py**

```
import wx
import wx.wizard

class WizardPage(wx.wizard.PyWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.wizard.PyWizardPage.__init__(self, parent)
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None
        self.initializeUI(title)

    def initializeUI(self, title):      
        # create grid layout manager    
        self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)

    def addWidget(self, widget, pos, span): 
        self.sizer.Add(widget, pos, span, wx.EXPAND)

    # getters and setters 
    def SetPrev(self, prev):
        self.prev = prev

    def SetNext(self, next):
        self.next = next

    def GetPrev(self):
        return self.prev

    def GetNext(self):
        return self.next
```

Then, in a separate file, I have a function to create each page.  The function for the first page calls the functions to create the other pages.  I also use helper functions called "browse1" and "browse2" to open a `wx.FileDialog` and such.

**pages.py**

```
import wx
from mywizard import * 

#### HELPER FUNCTIONS ####
def browse1(event, parent_page):
    wildcards = ...
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(parent_page, "Blahblah", "", "",
                            wildcards, wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST)

    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        global x1
        global bro1
        x1.SetValue(dlg.GetDirectory() + "\\" + dlg.GetFilename())
        bro1 = x1.GetValue()

def browse2(event, parent_page):
    wildcards = ...
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(parent_page, "Select new certificate", "", "",
                            wildcards, wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST)

    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        global x2
        global bro2
        x2.SetValue(dlg.GetDirectory() + "\\" + dlg.GetFilename())
        bro2 = x2.GetValue()

#### END HELPER FUNCTIONS ####

def create_page1(wizard):
    page1 = WizardPage(wizard, "Page 1")
    d = wx.StaticText(...)
    page1.addWidget(d, (2, 1), (1,5))

    page2 = create_update_certs_page2(wizard)
    page3 = create_update_certs_page3(wizard)

    # Set links
    page2.SetPrev(page1)
    page1.SetNext(page2)
    page3.SetPrev(page2)
    page2.SetNext(page3)

    return page1

def create_page2(wizard):
    page2 = WizardPage(wizard, "Page 2")

    b1 = wx.Button(page2, -1, "Browse...", wx.DefaultPosition, (85, 23))
    b1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt: browse1(evt, page2)) 

    global x1
    x1 = wx.TextCtrl(...) # the text area where the Browse path is populated

    b2 = wx.Button(page2, -1, "Browse...", wx.DefaultPosition, (85, 23))
    b2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt: browse2(evt, page2)) 

    global x2
    x2 = wx.TextCtrl(...) # the text area where the Browse path is populated

    page2.addWidget(b1, ..., ...)
    page2.addWidget(b2, ..., ...)
    page2.addWidget(x1, ..., ...)
    page2.addWidget(x2, ..., ...)

    return page2

def create_page3(wizard):
    print "bro1 is" + bro1 # these print empty strings
    print "bro2 is" + bro2 # not, the browse path and file that should be populated
```

Basically, the `x1` and `x2` refer to `wx.TextCtrl` widgets which I made global so I could populate them in the `browse1` and `browse2` functions.  Now, I want to access their populated values in the `bro1` and `bro2` variables in the `create_page3` function but nothing shows up.

And the main code in **pages.py** is:

```
app = wx.App(redirect = False)
wizard = wx.wizard.Wizard(None, -1, "Some Title")
wizard.SetPageSize((500, 350))

mypage1 = create_page1(wizard)

# Let's go!
wizard.RunWizard(mypage1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why should they be global? If you need their values in other functions or pages, consider passing them as arguments to your function or class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the values around as msvalkon mentioned. However I think subclassing wx.wizard.Wizard would be simpler. Then you can just create the various widgets inside the class and the their parents to different pages. This allows you to access the variables across pages rather easily. Here's an expansion on the answer I gave to your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21763512/how-do-i-disable-the-next-button-of-wxpython-wizard-page):

```
import wx
import wx.wizard

class WizardPage(wx.wizard.PyWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.wizard.PyWizardPage.__init__(self, parent)
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None
        self.initializeUI(title)

    def initializeUI(self, title):      
        # create grid layout manager    
        self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)

    def addWidget(self, widget, pos, span): 
        self.sizer.Add(widget, pos, span, wx.EXPAND)

    # getters and setters 
    def SetPrev(self, prev):
        self.prev = prev

    def SetNext(self, next):
        self.next = next

    def GetPrev(self):
        return self.prev

    def GetNext(self):
        return self.next

########################################################################
class MyWizard(wx.wizard.Wizard):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.wizard.Wizard.__init__(self, None, -1, "Some Title")
        self.SetPageSize((500, 350))

        mypage1 = self.create_page1()

        forward_btn = self.FindWindowById(wx.ID_FORWARD) 
        forward_btn.Disable()

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.onUpdate, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(1)

        self.RunWizard(mypage1)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def create_page1(self):
        page1 = WizardPage(self, "Page 1")
        d = wx.StaticText(page1, label="test")
        page1.addWidget(d, (2, 1), (1,5))

        self.text1 = wx.TextCtrl(page1)
        page1.addWidget(self.text1, (3,1), (1,5))

        self.text2 = wx.TextCtrl(page1)
        page1.addWidget(self.text2, (4,1), (1,5))

        page2 = WizardPage(self, "Page 2")
        page2.SetName("page2")
        self.text3 = wx.TextCtrl(page2)
        self.Bind(wx.wizard.EVT_WIZARD_PAGE_CHANGED, self.onPageChanged)
        page3 = WizardPage(self, "Page 3")

        # Set links
        page2.SetPrev(page1)
        page1.SetNext(page2)
        page3.SetPrev(page2)
        page2.SetNext(page3)

        return page1

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onPageChanged(self, event):
        """"""
        page = event.GetPage()
        print
        if page.GetName() == "page2":
            self.text3.SetValue(self.text2.GetValue())

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onUpdate(self, event):
        """
        Enables the Next button if both text controls have values
        """
        value_one = self.text1.GetValue()
        value_two = self.text2.GetValue()
        if value_one and value_two:
            forward_btn = self.FindWindowById(wx.ID_FORWARD) 
            forward_btn.Enable()
            self.timer.Stop()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def main():
    """"""
    wizard = MyWizard()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    main()
    app.MainLoop()
```

The idea here is to give each page a unique name and then catch the EVT_WIZARD_PAGE_CHANGED. In the handler, you can check what page you're on and update its contents accordingly.

Comment: Exactly what I meant in my answer below with code to supplement!

Comment: @Mike Driscoll: Again, I had to do something really janky with my code to get it to work but thank you for modeling it out for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what the most idiomatic way of doing it is but here's how I've dealt with this previously.

Subclass the `wx.wizard.Wizard`-class and bind the wx events `wx.wizard.EVT_WIZARD_ON_PAGE_CHANGING` and `wx.wizard.EVT_WIZARD_ON_PAGE_CHANGED` to methods of your class which make sure that data is consistently transferred back and forth pages.

The `wx.wizard.EVT_WIZARD_ON_PAGE_CHANGING` will be triggered when you press `next`. The method which handles this event is responsible for saving the current pages data.

The `wx.wizard.EVT_WIZARD_ON_PAGE_CHANGED` will trigger when the page has actually changed. The method which handles this event is responsible for populating the data from the previous page to the current pages fields or do whatever it is that you want to do with it.